# Uncaught TypeError: google.translate.TranslateService is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, typeerror

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<p>Привет Мир!</p>
<script type="text/javascript">var  gtElInit = function gtElInit() {var lib = new google.translate.TranslateService();lib.translatePage('ru', 'en', function () {});}</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=gtElInit&amp;client=wt"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Example 2

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<p>Привет Мир!</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=gtElInit&amp;client=wt"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var  gtElInit = function gtElInit() {var lib = new google.translate.TranslateService();lib.translatePage('ru', 'en', function () {});}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When run this page localy from desktop in Chrome - it works (russian words after page page load translate to english). So it works well in snippet here!

But when put page to website and run like normal site from web - it DONT WORK (russian words dont translate). Webpage here: http://www.shram.kiev.ua/bak/1.shtml

Error: *Uncaught TypeError: google.translate.TranslateService is not a constructor*

**I really dont know js but i trully need fix. Help pls. And pls give fix to my topic, because i read all topics about "is not a constructor" but dont understand :(**

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the translate library before you try to use it. On an HTML page, `<script>` tags are loaded in the order they appear, so you need to move the script tag loading Google translate above the script tag where you are trying to use it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do what you say. Move script loading google upper. Dont work againe. Second examle http://www.shram.kiev.ua/bak/1-2.shtml

Comment: That example makes it much easier to see what's going on. If you go into the console and type 'google.translate', you will see that it doesn't even have a property called TranslateService. I'd say whatever instructions you got this from are wrong or out of date. There is a function called TranslateElement, would that help you at all?

Comment: What i undestand - i use old instructions. In new instructions TranslateService() call TranslateElement(). I change name, but result dont work http://www.shram.kiev.ua/bak/1-3.shtml

Comment: sorry for my persistence and ignorance. I do all i understand :(

Comment: It would be helpful to post the instructions. It looks like TranslateElement takes different arguments than the TranslatePage function. I tried calling it on one of the DOM elements on your page but just got an object back with a bunch of properties I didn't understand.

Comment: I don't know how it works, I have no idea what library this is! But when I call `google.translate.TranslateElement()`, a Google bar loads at the top of the page offering to translate it - is that what you want to happen?

Comment: I dont have instructions too :(  upper Bar i dont need. I want code works like in example in snippet 1 and 2 - on page load, russion text converts to english